# ASP.net delegate functions get incorrect value of controls

Tags: asp.net, delegates, web-controls, asp.net-4.5

We had in our site some function calls that where conditional so we replaced them by delegated functions, the problem is that now in the function call the controls values are always the first ones (like its cached or so). What could be the cause?

Its better setting a delegate at initialization or using an if to call the correct function each time?

Simplified Example:

aspx:

```
<form runat="server" id="form1">
    <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" CombineScripts="False" EnableScriptGlobalization="True" EnableScriptLocalization="True" EnablePageMethods="True"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>

    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbViewPrinted" Text="View printed docs" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnFilter" runat="server" OnClick="btnFilter_Click"  />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

cs:

```
private delegate void LoadDataFuncx();
private LoadDataFuncx LoadData
{
    get
    {
        (LoadDataFuncx)Session["LoadData"];
    }
    set
    {
       Session["LoadData"]=value;
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Initialize();
    }
}

private void Initialize()
{
    if(conditionx==true)
    {
        LoadData=LoadDataCaseA;
    }
    else
    {
        LoadData=LoadDataCaseB;
    } 
}

private void LoadDataCaseA()
{
   //if called from delegate this always is false (even when the user checked the control or i set the value to checked by code later...)
   bool viewprinted=cbViewPrinted.Checked;
}

private void LoadDataCaseB()
{
   //if called from delegate this always is false (even when the user checked the control or i set the value to checked by code later...)
   bool viewprinted=cbViewPrinted.Checked;
}

protected void btnFilter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadData(); //calling from delegate...always gets the first control values (cached?) :S

    if(conditionx==true) //direct calling by checking condition, gets the current control value (correct)
    {
        LoadDataCaseA();
    }
    else
    {
        LoadDataCaseB();
    } 
}
```